# Is there a Microformat for the Hours a Business is open?

Tags: microformats

I was wondering if there was yet a Microformat for a business's hours of operation.

If not, who do I submit a standard to?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but I can see how this one would be useful. microformats.org has information on how to submit new formats at http://microformats.org/discuss/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After submitting the same question to the Microformats mailing list, I received a reply from someone named Martin Hepp who apparently has come up with a specification for this.

He provided me with the following links:

> The GoodRelations vocabulary provides
>   a standard way for business hours of
>   operation, see:
>
> http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/Rdfa4google
>
> http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/GoodRelations_and_Yahoo_SearchMonkey
>
> #
>
> the full spec and other materials are at
>
> http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/GoodRelations
>
> This is used e.g. by Bestbuy to expose the opening hours of their 1000k
>   stores in the US.
>
> Best
>
> Martin

Answer (score 10):

The most widely used markup for opening hours on the Web is [GoodRelations](http://purl.org/goodrelations/).

Here is an example:

```xml
<div xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
     xmlns:gr="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#" 
     xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">

  <div about="#store" typeof="gr:LocationOfSalesOrServiceProvisioning">
    <div property="rdfs:label" content="Pizzeria La Mamma"></div>
    <div rel="vcard:adr">
      <div typeof="vcard:Address">
        <div property="vcard:country-name" content="Germany"></div>
        <div property="vcard:locality" content="Munich"></div>
        <div property="vcard:postal-code" content="85577"></div>
        <div property="vcard:street-address" content="1234 Main Street"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div property="vcard:tel" content="+33 408 970-6104"></div>
    <div rel="foaf:depiction" resource="http://www.pizza-la-mamma.com/image_or_logo.png"></div>
    <div rel="vcard:geo">
      <div>
        <div property="vcard:latitude" content="48.08" datatype="xsd:float"></div>
        <div property="vcard:longitude" content="11.64" datatype="xsd:float"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursSpecification">
      <div about="#mon_fri" typeof="gr:OpeningHoursSpecification">
        <div property="gr:opens" content="08:00:00" datatype="xsd:time"></div>
        <div property="gr:closes" content="18:00:00" datatype="xsd:time"></div>
        <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursDayOfWeek" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Friday"></div>
        <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursDayOfWeek" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Thursday"></div>
        <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursDayOfWeek" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Wednesday"></div>
        <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursDayOfWeek" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Tuesday"></div>
        <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursDayOfWeek" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursSpecification">
      <div about="#sat" typeof="gr:OpeningHoursSpecification">
        <div property="gr:opens" content="08:30:00" datatype="xsd:time"></div>
        <div property="gr:closes" content="14:00:00" datatype="xsd:time"></div>
        <div rel="gr:hasOpeningHoursDayOfWeek" resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Saturday"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div rel="foaf:page" resource=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the Microformats suggestion from Ton does not really model that this is an opening hour, so a client cannot do a lot with it. GoodRelations markup is supported by many major companies. For example, BestBuy is using GoodRelations on all of their 1000+ store pages for indicating opening hours.

Answer (score 3):

A HTML micro-format can look like:

```
<ol class="business_hours">
<li class="monday">Maandag <span class="dtstart" title="08:00:00+01">9.00</span> - <span class="dtend" title="17:00:00+01">18.00</span> uur</li>
<li class="tuesday">Dinsdag <span class="dtstart" title="08:00:00+01">9.00</span> - <span class="dtend" title="17:00:00+01">18.00</span> uur</li>
<li class="wednesday">Woensdag <span class="dtstart" title="08:00:00+01">9.00</span> - <span class="dtend" title="17:00:00+01">18.00</span> uur</li>
<li class="thursday">Donderdag <span class="dtstart" title="08:00:00+01">9.00</span> - <span class="dtend" title="17:00:00+01">18.00</span> uur</li>
<li class="friday">Vrijdag <span class="dtstart" title="08:00:00+01">9.00</span> - <span class="dtend" title="17:00:00+01">18.00</span> uur</li>
<li class="saturday">Zaterdag <span class="dtstart" title="08:00:00+01">9.00</span> - <span class="dtend" title="15:00:00+1">16.00</span> uur</li>
<li>Zondag Gesloten</li>
</ol>
```

Excuse my Dutch :)

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

Microformat has updated their wiki with a suggested way of implementing Operating Hours based on hCalendar.

http://microformats.org/wiki/operating-hours

Answer (score 3):

See https://schema.org/openingHours

Schema.org is an initiative launched on 2 June 2011 by Bing, Google and Yahoo.

An example:

```
<strong>Openning Hours:</strong>
<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Tu,Th 16:00-20:00">
    Tuesdays and Thursdays 4-8pm
</time>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps http://microformats.org/ may be of use...

Comment: I'd vote you up but your score (10K exactly) is such a round number.

Comment: upvoting for what, exactly? It not exactly a detailed answer.

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps the upvote is for my high speed googling... perhaps OP's G key is gubbed

Answer (score 0):

If is still useful, you should submit to the microformats community using their wiki: microformats.org.

In this [link](http://microformats.org/wiki/process) you have all the existing process to propose a new microformat specification.

Hope that helps.